# Date issue in js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

```
let date = "2021-07-31-T18:30:00.000Z"
date = new Date(date)
let nextDate = new Date()

// I have made a addDays function which returns a date.
nextDate = date.addDays(1)
```

Mongoose query:

```
$match:    {
            created: {
                $gt: new Date(date),
                $lte: new Date(nextDate)
                }
            }
```

I want to change the date from "2021-07-31-T18:30:00.000Z" to **"2021-07-31-T00:00:00.000Z"** so that my query can filter correct data. How can I achieve this?

I tried using setHours but it won't work.

Comment: `date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`. Define "didn't work".

Comment: adding a day does not then subtract 18.5 hours